What is a way to calculate the maximum number of remaining competitors in this variation of the game of musical chairs?
For those who don't know what musical chairs is, it is a game where players compete to find a seat amongst a slowly dwindling amount of chairs. While not having a chair at the end of a round usually results in losing the game, in this variation, the lose condition is to spend a certain amount of time without a chair total throughout the game.
A simple example game would start with 100 chairs and 100 competitors and to lose they must be without a chair for a round+1sec. 10 chairs are removed each round for 9 rounds.
I believe at the end of 9 rounds (10 chairs remaining), there could at most be 30 remaining players. This happens when round 8 has 20 people who've never lost any amount of time with their chairs swap out with 10 people with one second remaining for the 9th round. This example ends with 30 people with one second remaining in their total banked time.
My question is how to formulate the maximum remaining competitors at a certain round for 1) a non linear number of chairs removed i.e. 10% each round, and 2) a variable amount of time given to players before they are disqualified?
I believe the answer doesn't really change much if chairs exceed competitors, so feel free to formulate assuming that the game starts with the same number of contestants and chairs. Also I assume the maximum number of players remaining requires some level of cooperation by what would normally be competitors, but I ask you to assume the goal of players is to keep as many people in the game.
I have a mostly unsuccessful attempt at solving it by calculating the sum total of the time allotted to all competitors and working backwards from the end to see how much time expenditure is necessary to preserve some number of people from the prior round.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
